# Add custom content in the middle of Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I go about changing this code so that it inserts the custom content after half of the paragraphs in a given post? If a post has 12 paragraphs, the content should be inserted after number 6. If it has 100, it should be inserted after number 50.

I have found this code online, where you can specify a hard coded number of paragraphs:

```
<?php
//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
 $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';
 if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
 return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
 }
return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
 $closing_p = '</p>';
 $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
 foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
 if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
 $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
 }
 if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
 $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
 }
 }

 return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

I do not know enough PHP to make it dynamic. I have not found a dynamic answer to this elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
//Insert ads after half of the paragraphs in a post
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
 $ad_code = '<div>CODE HERE</div>';
 if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() && in_category('29') ) {
 return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, $content );
 }
return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $content ) {
 $closing_p = '</p>';
 $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
 $paragraph_id = round(count($paragraphs) / 2);
 foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
 if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
 $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
 }
 if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
 $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
 }
 }
 return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Here I also added a category check.

Comment: this will insert the code inside quote block since it has P tag inside.